# Any conjectures about Jack Littlewood-Richardson coefficients when Schur LR > 1?

Tags: co.combinatorics, polynomials, combinatorial-identities, littlewood-richardson-coefficients

Stanley famously conjectured (["Some combinatorial properties of Jack symmetric functions"](https://math.mit.edu/%7Erstan/pubs/pubfiles/73.pdf) Adv. in Math. (77) 1989, doi:[10.1016/0001-8708(89)90015-7](https://doi.org/10.1016/0001-8708%2889%2990015-7), [MR1014073](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1014073), [Zbl 0743.05072](https://zbmath.org/0743.05072)) that the Jack Littlewood-Richardson coefficient $\langle J_\mu J_\nu, J_\lambda\rangle$ is a non-negative integer polynomial in the Jack deformation parameter $\alpha$. He also proposed a 'stronger' form of this conjecture when the corresponding Schur LR coefficient satisfies $c_{\mu\nu}^{\lambda} = 1$, namely that in this case there should be a formula of the type
$$
\langle J_\mu J_\nu, J_\lambda\rangle = \left(\prod_{b\in \mu} A_\mu(b)\right)\left(\prod_{b\in \nu} B_\nu(b)\right)\left(\prod_{b\in \lambda} C_\lambda(b)\right)
$$
where $A,B,C$ are a choice of upper or lower hook length for every box $b$ in each of the three partitions. Such a formula is manifestly a non-negative integral polynomial in $\alpha$.

My question is: are there any (even loose) conjectural forms for the structure of the Jack LR coefficients in any case where $c_{\mu\nu}^{\lambda} > 1$?

Comment: It would be helpful to add a link to the paper where this was 'famously conjectured'.  Have you checked the papers citing it? That would be the best way to answer your question.

Comment: OP updated. I've read several papers citing it, but there are over 600 and I'm far from an expert.

Comment: MathSciNet has some 250 citations, which narrows it down a bit. Plus, if one searches for certain keywords in titles and abstracts, that leaves just a handful of papers. For example, among the papers citing Stanley that have "Littlewood-Richardson" in the title, this may be relevant : https://doi.org/10.1093/imrn/rnq126

Comment: Hi, Ryan! Good to see you here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a new preprint out today regarding this question: [The Stanley Conjecture Revisited](https://arxiv.org/abs/2401.01582).

In this paper, I conjectured that all Jack LR coefficients obey a 'windowing' property, that allows to reduce the computation of these coefficients to a smaller sub-problem.

Assuming this conjecture, many explicit formulas are presented for the Jack LR coefficient $c_{21,21}^{321}(\alpha)$, which is the simplest case that has Schur LR $c=2$.